# How can I build this plugin in XCode?

Tags: xcode

I'm totally new to XCode 3 (running Snow Leopard) and have no idea what I'm doing. I'm trying to

https://github.com/johan/QuickJSON

The target of this XCode file is "QuickJSON.some_extenesion". It's a QuickLook plugin which kinda looks like a lego block. I tried going to Build -> Build and I checked the build folder, but I couldn't find the target there but a bunch of other files. The only file I'm expecting to see is the QuickJSON plugin target file. Does anyne know where I can find it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project Builds fine for me. Initially, the Product "QuickSON.qlgenerator" is red, but becomes available after building.

[image]

Try downloading a fresh project and press Build again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Where can I locate the QuickJSON.qlgenerator file after building it?

Comment: I found a "QuickJSON.qlgenerator" file in the debug folder. Do you kno can I find a non-debug version? Thanks!

Comment: YOu need to build for Release, otherwise, it's Debug.